# Record ASP.Net user in IIS logs

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, logging

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 application (on IIS 6.0) which uses ASP.NET forms authentication. In my IIS logs, I have extended logging turned on including the cs-username field. Even after a user has logged in to my site, the cs-username still displays '-'.

Is there a way to get the authenticated ASP.NET user's name to appear in the username field in the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily.

cs-username by default is the HTTP authentication username, not forms authentication. You might be able to write an ISAPI DLL to intercept the call, parse the ASP.NET auth token cookie, decrypting it if you have to and retrieve the username from the membership providerthen intercept SF_NOTIFY_LOG and respond to the ON_LOG event to set the right name, but it's non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Alernatively, use the ASP.NET memebership provider to write some customised codes to record them in the database!

Answer (score 0):

yep, pretty lame of asp.net...you'd think they would have integrated it better w/ the IIS logs :-P

You can use this isapi filter, but I'm not sure it'll work for IIS7 (Windows 2008).  Should work fine in Win2003:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/isapilogger.aspx